# How to authenticate http request, for accessing gcp API services (python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

In order to get the enabled GCP-api services list, I am trying to get the service.list as per this HTTP request in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/list#http-request).

Here's my code:

```
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account


auth = HTTPBasicAuth('myusername@gmail.com','xyz....')

url = 'https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-proj-id123/services'

headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json"
 }

response = requests.request(
   "GET",
   url,
   headers=headers,
   auth=auth
 )
# a=json.loads(response.text)
print(response.text)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: I need a way to get the respond as per this [link](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/list#http-request), either by *service account* or by *api token* . I have service account key (`credential.json`) but I don't know where to put for http request. kindly suggest me the procedures.

Comment: Instructions on how to set up authorization are located [here](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/getting-started#enable). `credentials.json` should be located in your home directory.

Comment: Google Cloud does not support HTTP Basic Authorization. For most APIs, you must use a Bearer token. **Authorization: Bearer TOKEN**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encourage you to consider using Google's SDKs whenever you interact with Google's services.

Not only do the services provide language-specific resource types that facilitate creating requests and responses, but you get simpler auth, logging etc. etc. etc.

Documented:

- [google_auth](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/user-guide.html)
- [Python Client for Service Management API](https://github.com/googleapis/python-service-management)
- [list_services](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/servicemanagement/latest/google.cloud.servicemanagement_v1.services.service_manager.ServiceManagerClient#google_cloud_servicemanagement_v1_services_service_manager_ServiceManagerClient_list_services) --> [`ListServicesPager`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/servicemanagement/latest/google.cloud.servicemanagement_v1.services.service_manager.pagers.ListServicesPager) --> [`ListServicesResponse`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/servicemanagement/latest/google.cloud.servicemanagement_v1.types.ListServicesResponse) --> [`ManagedService`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/servicemanagement/latest/google.cloud.servicemanagement_v1.types.ManagedService)
- [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) --> [Service Management](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-management/reference/rest/) --> [`services.list`](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-management/reference/rest/v1/services/list) --> [Response](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-management/reference/rest/v1/services/list#response-body) --> [ManagedService](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-management/reference/rest/v1/services#ManagedService)

Setup:

```sh
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
ACCOUNT=[[YOUR-ACCOUNT]]

python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

python3 -m pip install google-auth
python3 -m pip install google-cloud-service-management

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/viewer

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL}

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json

python3 ./main.py
```

`main.py`:

```
import google.auth
from google.cloud import servicemanagement_v1

credentials,project = google.auth.default()

client = servicemanagement_v1.ServiceManagerClient()

# How to construct the Request
rqst = {
     # Purely for example
    "pageSize": 5,
     # List only project's services
    "consumer_id: "project:{project}".format(
        project=project
    )
}

# Response is a ServiceListPager
resp = client.list_services(request=rqst)

# Which is iterable
for managed_service in resp:
    try:
        # This is a quirk of gRPC Transcoding
        # Convert a ManagedService to JSON
        j=servicemanagement_v1.ManagedService.to_json(managed_service)
        print(j)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Yields:

```
{
  "serviceName": "abusiveexperiencereport.googleapis.com",
  "producerProjectId": ""
}
{
  "serviceName": "acceleratedmobilepageurl.googleapis.com",
  "producerProjectId": ""
}
{
  "serviceName": "accessapproval.googleapis.com",
  "producerProjectId": ""
}
...
```

Comment: here how can i filter the disabled service by using my gcp project id

Comment: Please read the documentation. You can include the `consumerId` set to the Project ID in the request.

Comment: i have tried by mentioning "consumerId"
`rqst = {
    # "pageSize": 5 # Purely for example    
    "consumerId" : "my-proj-id-123"
}`

**but i am getting error**
`pb_type = self._meta.fields[key].pb_type
KeyError: 'consumerId'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

"Unknown field for {}: {}".format(self.__class__.__name__, key)
ValueError: Unknown field for ListServicesRequest: consumerId`

Comment: I'll try it for you later this morning when I get to my computer

Comment: Did you set `consumerId` to be `project:{PROJECT-ID}` replacing `{PROJECT-ID}` with your actual Project ID?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of using `consumer_id`

Comment: Again it  showed Key error by highlighting formate. But I directly tried here `resp = client.list_services(consumer_id='project:my-proj-id-123')`  **It works fine** thanks bro thank u soo much

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it's working and pleased that you were willing to try the SDK.